# GetAttributeValue coming back as null

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, entity-attribute-value

This has been perplexing me all day. I am attempting to do some checks in an if statement regarding attribute values after querying another entity in my code. Post query I am getting the GUID of the entity I am looking for, but when I attempt to get an attribute value using that guid, my attributes (hc_accountstatus and hc_contractchannelcode) are both coming back null.

```
_tracer.Trace("account details results greater than or equal to one");

Guid accountDetailsId = (Guid)accountDetailsResults[0].Attributes["hc_accountdetailsid"];

var accountDetails = new Entity("hc_accountdetails", accountDetailsId);
var accountChannel = accountDetails.GetAttributeValue<int?>("hc_contractchannelcode");
var accountStatus = accountDetails.GetAttributeValue<int?>("hc_accountstatus");
```

When I hover over accountDetails I see that I am returning an entity, with the correct GUID of the accountDetails I was expecting to return. I have tried `accountDetails.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("hc_accountstatus");` I have also tried `(OptionSetValue)accountDetailsResults[0].Attributes["hc_accountstatus"];`

I made sure that all spelling is correct, and that the expected account details entity has values that are not null. Am I missing something obvious here? I tried to return a column set but couldn't find anything that made intellisense happy. I also referenced other code that is working like this in our repo, and asked 2 developers in my company and both of them told me this is exactly how they would do it.

Comment: Can we see the code with the attributes?

Comment: ```if ((accountStatus != null && accountStatus.Value == Constants.AccountStatus.Client && accountChannel != null && accountChannel.Value == Constants.ContractChannel.DirectHCWS) || 
                                (accountStatus != null && accountStatus.Value == Constants.AccountStatus.House && accountChannel != null && accountChannel.Value == Constants.ContractChannel.DirectHCWS))
                            {
                                return;
                            }```

Comment: My constants are being read as ints from code side. For example Client == 948050001, plus others etc

Comment: To add new information, please [edit] your question instead of posting it as comment.

Comment: your code doesn't contain the "Retrieve" part of this hc_accountdetails entity. Just assigning the Guid to the entity doesn't automatically retrieve it, in your code (as it is written) you are doing a GetAttributeValue of an empty entity (where only the Id is set)

Answer (score 0):

Few troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure, however you are getting the results in `accountDetailsResults` the source query should have `hc_contractchannelcode` And `hc_accountstatus` in the select columns/attributes list. It may be fetchxml or query expression but make sure it’s in the querying attributes list. And for testing - take a record with values in attributes
2. You may be getting mixed between two variables - `accountDetails` which is new object whereas `accountDetailsResults` is retrieved object
3. This is better way of doing it

—

```
var accountChannel = accountDetailsResults[0].GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("hc_contractchannelcode");
var accountStatus = accountDetailsResults[0].GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("hc_accountstatus");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Guido Preite you hit the nail on the head! I did did a _service.Retrieve and was able to get the data that I needed. Thanks to everyone for their input!

```
_tracer.Trace("account details results greater than or equal to one");
                        Guid accountDetailsId = (Guid)accountDetailsResults[0].Attributes["hc_accountdetailsid"];
                        var accountDetails = new Entity("hc_accountdetails", accountDetailsId);
                        var retrievedAccountDetails = _service.Retrieve("hc_accountdetails", accountDetailsId, new ColumnSet("hc_accountstatus", "hc_contractchannelcode"));
                        var accountChannel = retrievedAccountDetails.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("hc_contractchannelcode");
                        var accountStatus = retrievedAccountDetails.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("hc_accountstatus");
```

Comment: You might have missed my answer :)